# Get name of bgl_RenderedTexture in Python

Tags: python, game-engine, shaders

I want to let the GPU create a mipmap for the framebuffer texture that's available as **bgl_RenderedTexture** in the custom filters.

It shouldn't be difficult. I just put some code into the post_draw list:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, bgl_RenderedTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

But there's no variable bgl_RenderedTexture. Is there a way to get the texture name for the framebuffer?